# Pronomes demostrativos e colocação pronominal

Tags: português-brasileiro, colocação-pronominal

Estou estudando para concurso, no Brasil. Estou vendo muitas fontes, talvez informais, de colocação pronominal, que dizem que os pronomes demonstrativos são fatores de próclise. Até aí, tudo bem, porque seria até razoável assumir isto, já que existem outros pronomes que têm a função de atrativo, como os relativos, indefinidos e os interrogativos (em início de frase).

Mas, as fontes "formais" que estou estudando, como Cegalla e Celso Cunha, nunca citam o pronome demonstrativo como caso de próclise. Somente, talvez indiretamente, nos casos de oração em ordem inversa, Cunha usa um exemplo em orações inversas, onde uma delas inicia-se com pronome demonstrativo:

> Tiraram mais que na ceifa; isso te digo eu. (*Alves Redol, G, 108.*)

A dúvida permanece (haha). Talvez as fontes informais estão generalizando uma regra? Talvez as orações inversas têm muitos casos similares (com pronomes demonstrativos)? Alguém conhece alguma fonte que os confirme como proclíticos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha, eu nunca aprendi que pronomes demonstrativos (por si mesmos) induziam a próclise. Mas, como a língua é dinâmica e eu poderia estar simplesmente errado, consultei aqui um par de gramáticas brasileiras *famosas*:

- Evanildo Bechara não menciona pronomes demonstrativos em *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa* (Editora Nova Fronteira, 37ª edição, 2009).
- Pasquale Cipro Neto (ele mesmo) e Ulisses Infante, em *Gramática da Língua Portuguesa* (Editora Scipione, 3ª edição, 2010), consideram a colocação pronominal "uma questão tão pouco relevante que não se deve perder tempo" com ela. Os autores até admitem como *correto* um uso comum, mas normalmente perseguido, de próclise: a alusão à língua falada brasileira:

> *Me faça um favor: me esquece!*

Mas nada especificamente sobre pronomes demonstrativos.

As fontes na internet, de fato, parecem concordar massivamente com a ideia dos pronomes demonstrativos promovendo a próclise. Eles devem estar extraindo esta informação de uma fonte comum, que provavelmente deve ser alguma gramática que se antecipou às demais e normatizou o uso corrente.

Estou tentado a dizer que, para concursos, a ênclise é preferível, na ausência de outros fatores de indução. Bancas de concursos (exceto vestibulares) costumam ser muito conservadoras, neste sentido.

Comment: Interessante, não sei se estou me apegando a detalhes que não são tão importantes, já que ainda não compreendo muito bem a gramatica. Talvez eu esteja com medo de aprender errado, não sei.

É "seguro" dizer que as bancas, conservadoras que são, não se preocupariam com esse fato já que ainda não foi "estabelecido formalmente" que pronomes demonstrativos são fatores de próclise? 

Eu sei que normalmente ênclise é preferível, meu medo é eles apresentares o pronome em próclise e perguntar se esta correto ou até mesmo pedirem pra julgar uma frase que afirma a regra dos demonstrativos...

Comment: @Luiggia2b1 "não sei se estou me apegando a detalhes que não são tão importantes" Esta é uma opinião dos autores, eles acham que não é essencial para um falante PT-BR dominar este conteúdo (o que eu concordo). Só que o livro deles é feito para pessoas comuns, e não para concurseiros. O que eles consideram "importante" pode não o ser para você.

Comment: "meu medo é eles apresentares o pronome em próclise e perguntar se esta correto ou até mesmo pedirem pra julgar uma frase que afirma a regra dos demonstrativos" Isso só pode ocorrer em duas situações: (1) o concurso oferece uma gramática na bibliografia recomendada, aí você precisa conferir o que o autor dela considera como norma; (2) a banca do concurso está se colocando no risco de ter que julgar dezenas de recursos de candidatos e possivelmente anular a questão. Ainda assim, se eu tivesse que arriscar, iria de ênclise.

Comment: Faz sentido, valeu!

Comment: @Luiggia2b1 Fico feliz de você ter apreciado minha resposta, mas aqui vai um conselho: espere mais um pouco antes de aceitar uma resposta. Alguns usuários podem se sentir desencorajados de contribuir se a pergunta já tiver uma resposta aceita, e eles podem ter respostas melhores que a aceita. Se você souber inglês e tiver algum tempo livre, tem uma discussão sobre isso lá no [site principal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18573/is-accepting-an-answer-discouraging-more-answers/49307).

Comment: Obrigado, confesso que não li as Guidelines como deveria e pensei que seria "rude", digamos assim, não aceitar a resposta de prontidão haha Vou ler sim!

Comment: @Luiggia2b1 Não é guideline, é mais uma dica mesmo. Não é rude, ninguém vai se importar de esperar algumas horas.

Comment: @Luiggia2b1 e Ramon, tive a dar uma vista de olhos no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/x.asp) e na literatura e imprensa do Brasil recente é bem mais comum o pronome demonstrativo seguido de próclise. Já no século sXIX era o contrário, como ainda hoje é em Portugal. Mas se isso fosse critério, então nas locuções verbais há muito tempo que no Brasil a próclise ao verbo principal é muito comum.

Comment: @Jacinto O foco do problema desta pergunta está na palavra **concurso**. As equipes por trás destas provas são o mais recluso bastião dos puristas da língua portuguesa no Brasil, que ainda lamentam a ascensão do modernismo mas, paradoxalmente, adaptaram-se quase que imediatamente ao novo Acordo Ortográfico. Os únicos critérios que eles reconhecem são as gramáticas e os dicionários. Mesmo a academia e o direito são ignorados (e, por vezes, até criticados) por eles.